# How to set the text node value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="votes">
    <b>5</b> Votes
    <a id="vote-' + element_id +'" href="#" class="vote-btn"></a>
</div>
```

I have manage to get the text after 5 i.e. votes using:

```
var voteTextNode = $(this).parent('div').contents().filter(function() {
                    return this.nodeType == 3;  
                });
var voteText = voteTextNode.text();
```

now i want to change this text to vote which is respective number of votes . I have tried this:

```
voteNewText = ( newCount == '1' ) ? 'Vote' : 'Votes';
voteTextNode.text(voteNewText);
```

but it does not work for me. I have also tried the code from this link:
[How can I get, manipulate and replace a text node using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046482/how-can-i-get-manipulate-and-replace-a-text-node-using-jquery)
but it also wont work for me tell me where i am doing wrong

Comment: If some sort of reason why you can not wrap Votes in <span>? Manipulated by DOM faster and easier than with the plain text.

Comment: actually span have style defined which does not matches the design in this area. i know i can change style of that particular span but just want to know if there is an alternate way of doing that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put it in a span

```
<div class="votes">
    <b>5</b> <span id="votesTxt">Votes</span>
    <a id="vote-' + element_id +'" href="#" class="vote-btn"></a>
</div>
```

and then

```
$("#votesTxt").text(( newCount == '1' ) ? 'Vote' : 'Votes');
```

**EDIT** if you don't wish to use span then just change the text for the element after the b tag:

```
$("#votes b:first")[0].nextSibling.data = (( newCount == '1' ) ? 'Vote' : 'Votes');
```

Comment: here you have removed the text votes by default but i need that since the post already have some votes. i need to change it when the current user clicks on the vote button.

Answer (score 5):

As you have seen, jQuery is not really made for handling text nodes. Your `var voteTextNode` will be a jQuery instance, holding a set of text nodes. You can hardly manipulate them using `.text()`, which would  add some new TextNodes into them.

Yet, this should work:

```
 $(this).parent('div').contents().each(function() {
     // iterate over all child nodes
     if (this.nodeType == 3)
        this.data = "Vote";
 });
```

But with plain dom methods it may be clearer:

```
 var countTextNode, voteTextNode;
 $(this).parent('div').find('b').each(function() {
      countTextNode = this.firstChild;
      voteTextNode = this.nextSibling;
 });
 return function setVotes(num) {
      countTextNode.data = num;
      votTextNode.data = num == 1 ? 'Vote' : 'Votes';
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Treat it as the DOM tree it is: what you probably want is to get the first `<b>` element inside each `<div>` with class "votes" and then change the text in the text node that immediately follows it. jQuery is good at selecting and iterating over elements so use it for this part if you want. Once you've got the `<b>` elements, switch to regular DOM. Here's an example:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qq3T7/

Code:

```
$("div.votes").find("b:first").each(function() {
    this.nextSibling.data = ($(this).text() == "1") ? " Vote" : " Votes";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the initial markup? You'll have a much easier time doing this if you just wrap the text you want to change in a tag:

```
<span id="votetext">Vote</span>
```

And then you can easily set the text:

```
$('#votetext').text('Votes');
```