# Change Anchor Text while keeping the FontAwesome Icon inlined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using WordPress so i could only change the HTML through custom JS.

This is the HTML

```
<li class="submit-listing"><a href="http://localhost/proficientlink/post-your-ad/"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Submit Listing</a></li>
```

I already tried all of these:

```
$(".submit-listing a").html("<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Post You Ad");

$(".submit-listing a").html(function(){
$(this).find("i").addClass("fa fa-plus");
this.nodeValue = "Post Your Ad";
});
```

but none of these work. I also tried this : [How can I get, manipulate and replace a text node using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046482/how-can-i-get-manipulate-and-replace-a-text-node-using-jquery), but nothing seems to work with me.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `replace` works:

```
$('.submit-listing a').html(function (i, el) {
  return el.replace('Submit Listing', 'Post your ad');
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fatpjr9p/)**

Comment: Tried this! It worked as well :) Thanks again, Andy :)

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your code should be,

```
$(".submit-listing a").html("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Post You Ad");
```

Change the double quotes to single quotes because JavaScript treats them as closing strings.

Comment: I'd actually have the quotes the other way around fwiw: `$('.submit-listing a').html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Post You Ad');`. That way the HTML looks like HTML.

Comment: but i tried removing "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>" using single quote, it worked though.. unluckily i needed to keep the fontawesome icon.

Comment: I have copied/pasted your code and it worked! really dont know why (?.?)

Comment: Glad that I could help!